# How to stop method execution in $scope.$on until upload ends

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, umbraco

I'm trying to upload a batch of files on form save click. The method should wait until the file uploading ends and then do the saving. Right now the method doesn't wait and saves before the files are uploaded.

Here is my code

```
$scope.$on("formSubmitting", function (ev, args) {
        $scope.uploadPendingFiles();
    });
```

uploadPendingFiles(); is doing XMLHttpRequest send.

Any idea how to do it?

**EDIT**

as suggested, more info:

On the form i can pick some files to upload but the uploading should only start when user clicks the save button. The parent controller broadcasts **formSubmitting** on save click and i want to display loading gif until all the files are uploaded.

Comment: your information is incomplete to me. I get your idea but still cannot guess how you want to implement it. are you broadcasting an upload event? are you planning to fire the request on a resolved callback of another promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause your task is based on legacy code, the solution can be using `preventDefault()` method for `click` event of submit button.

So i've prepared [sample](https://codepen.io/raliev/pen/VELOEL), describing your case (please, say if there is misunderstanding in it).

About event propagation in a few words you can read in this [article](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

@TestzWCh, it seems, that you need use promises. The uploading method (with http-request) must return `$q.defer().promise`, that you will use like this:

`FileService.uploadingMethodPromise().then(function(result){
   // do your logic with result -- enable Save button, or send saving request..
})`

Is there anything i can do for your task?

Comment: since it's legacy code i can't really change it to chain it like that, thanks for the effort